# How to define maxOccurs anywhere in element's scope in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to know if there's a way how to define maxOccurs of `content` in `abc` element? It doesn't matter how many of `content` elements there are in `a`, `b` and `c` as long as there's no more than x number of occurrences in the whole `abc`. Thanks in advance!

```
<abc>
    <a>
        <content>AA</content>
        <content>AAA</content>
    </a>

    <b>
        <content>B</content>
    </b>

    <c>
        <content>CCC</content>
        <content>C</content>
    </c>
</abc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Would have to be checked out-of-band wrt XSD.

### XSD 1.1

Possible using `xs:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="abc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="HasContentType"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="HasContentType"/>
        <xs:element name="c" type="HasContentType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(*/content) &lt;= 5"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="HasContentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string" 
                  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Note:** The above assertion constrains the total number of `content` element occurrences within child elements of `abc`.  Should you want to constrain occurrences anywhere in the hierarchy beneath `abc` as your title suggests in saying *anywhere in element's scope*, you could instead use this assertion:

```
      <xs:assert test="count(.//content) &lt;= 5"/>
```